# Qualcomm Hexagon: Vector memory load intrinsic?

Tags: assembly, simd, intrinsics, qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

I would like perform SIMD operations, e.g., on a MAC-loop with Hexagon. While there are intrinsics on e.g. multiply-accumulate vector data, I don't find any C-intrinsics on vector memory loads and stores.

Are there any or do I need to write asm code to do so?

Comment: Looks like you just cast and deref a pointer, as in : [Enabling HVX in Hexagon DSP by using instruction intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49447950)

Comment: Thanks. But how do I then increment this pointer and load new values? It seems to me that there are no C-intrinsics for memory loads and stores, and, there is no intrinsic for data alignment, right?

Comment: I don't know HVX; does it even have two kinds of load instructions (alignment required vs. unaligned like x86 `movdqu` vs. `movdqa`)?  If not, deref of a vector-pointer can express everything that's possible in asm.  As for how to increment a pointer, C supports pointer math in general, on `char*`, `int*` or whatever type you want, and you can cast the result to a vector pointer.  So `*(vec_ptr*)(charptr + 64)` or `*(1 + (vec_ptr*)p)`.  Same as for pointer math with SSE or NEON intrinsics.